# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: index=0 length=0 in get sqlite database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to open a writeable SQLite database with this code...

```
public DataAdapterForServieClass open() throws SQLException {
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
```

However I am getting the following error on the `db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();` line...

```
06-10 11:58:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(548): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-10 11:58:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(548): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: index=0 length=0
06-10 11:58:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(548):     at android.app.ContextImpl.validateFilePath(ContextImpl.java:1518)
06-10 11:58:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(548):     at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:725)
06-10 11:58:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(548):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
06-10 11:58:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(548):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:149)
```

This is the code of my `DBHelper` class...

```
static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
            + " to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS titles");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Could someone please help me.

Comment: Please provide the code of DBHelper class

Comment: public DataAdapterForServieClass open() throws SQLException 
{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

it was the dbhelper class code, and it is where error occured

Comment: @KishorDgupta, we need the code of your `DBHelper` class, not the code where you call it. What is the code of your `getWritableDatabase()` method in `DBHelper`?

Comment: given, dbhelper is a object of databasehelper class, i give the code of that class

Comment: It looks like the database's name is being passed as the empty string.  But this is only a guess until we see the code.

Comment: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

i use the code in this link, 
the code works fine previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `getWritableDatabase()` for the first time, it will call the following methods, according to the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)...

```
onCreate(SQLiteDatabase)
onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int)
onOpen(SQLiteDatabase)
```

You don't have any code in your `onCreate()` method - you'll need to do something here before it will work, such as this...

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.openOrCreateDatabase("/come/example/mydatabase",null);
}
```

Look at the `checkDataBase()` method in the [link you posted](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) where it calls `openDatabase()` - this does the same thing, and is the important piece of code that you're missing. You need to create the database before you can do anything with it.

Also make sure that somewhere in your code you are creating your DBHelper instance, so that it calls the `super()` method. Like this...

```
DBHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
```

Comment: thanks .i was using code differently. one class for create and class to open. because for maintain a MVC model, thanks i got it. U r great